# Count the number of mentions and direct messages made by the user without authentication

Tags: twitter

Is there any way to find out the total number of mentions and direct messages made by the user? Suppose my Twitter screen name is "ABCD". I want to calculate the total number of mentions made by me so far.

Answer (score 0):

Not without authentication. According to the developer docs,  [statuses/user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline) "Requires user context", and this data is not included anywhere else as far as I know.